# How can I delete elements before another element in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is my html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Item name" aria-label="Item name" required>
        <input type="file" class="form-control mt-3" required>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 w-100 removeItem">Remove item</button>
```

This is my JS:

```
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('removeItem')) {
        // e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', 'test');
        console.log(e.target.parentNode)
    }
});

addItemBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (createBinModalForm.checkValidity()) {
        addItemBtn.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<hr/>');
        addItemBtn.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Item name" aria-label="Item name" required>
        <input type="file" class="form-control mt-3" required>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 w-100 removeItem">Remove item</button>
        `);
    }
})
```

How can I use this JavaScript to remove the three elements before the target button is clicked but. not anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Element.previousElementSibling to get the element right before and then use .remove() to remove it.
Something like this:

```js
const deleteElementsButton = document.getElementById("deleteElementsButton");

deleteElementsButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // how many elements do you want to delete
    const nextSibling = button.previousElementSibling.remove(); // removes the element just before the button
  }
})
```

```html
<div>Previews element 1</div>
<div>Previews element 2</div>
<div>Previews element 3</div>
<div>Previews element 4</div>
<button id="deleteElementsButton">Delete previews 3 elements</button>
```

More info here: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-next-and-previous-siblings-of-an-element-with-vanilla-js/

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: To delete an item you should use the name of that item `elementToDelete.remove()`.
For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove

Option 2: In case you want to remove more than one element you use innerHTML.
So if you want to delete your HTML container you should use
`document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = “<div>Here you should enter the HTML code you need or want.</div>”;`
For more info about `innerHTML` you can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
In regards to option 2 the elements you want to delete should be in separate container with class attribute for this to work. Otherwise you could delete elements that you want to keep.